# What is the meaning of the ${0##...} syntax with variable, braces and hash character in bash?

Tags: bash, variables, syntax, curly-braces

I just saw some code in bash that I didn't quite understand.  Being the newbie bash scripter, I'm not sure what's going on.

```
echo ${0##/*}
echo ${0}
```

I don't really see a difference in output in these two commands (prints the script name).  Is that `#` just a comment?  And what's with the `/*`.  If it is a comment, how come it doesn't interfere with the closing `}` brace?

Can anyone give me some insight into this syntax?

Comment: This is POSIX shell syntax, so it works with `sh` as well as `bash`.  See the [Parameter Expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) section of the POSIX [Shell Command Language](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html) document.  Also see [Removing part of a string (BashFAQ/100 (How do I do string manipulation in bash?))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Removing_part_of_a_string).

Answer (score 106, accepted):

See the section on [Substring removal](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal) on the [parameter expansion page of the bash-hackers' wiki](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe):

> `${PARAMETER#PATTERN}` and `${PARAMETER##PATTERN}`
>
> This form is to remove the described pattern trying to match it from the beginning of the string. The operator `#` will try to remove the shortest text matching the pattern, while `##` tries to do it with the longest text matching.
>
> Example string (just a quote from a big man):
>
> `MYSTRING="Be liberal in what you accept, and conservative in what you send"`
>
> | Syntax | Result |
> | --- | --- |
> | `${MYSTRING#*in}` | <del>Be liberal in</del> what you accept, and conservative in what you send. |
> | `${MYSTRING##*in}` | <del>Be liberal in what you accept, and conservative in</del> what you send. |

Comment: Would you mind adding a link to the relevant section in the Bash reference manual to this? For example https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Comment: As also suggested by the footnote and the previous comment, the ABS is not a good canonical reference; this answer could be improved by citing authoritative or at least respected sources instead.

Comment: Consider the objections to linking the ABS reiterated; it teaches a lot of antipatterns and bad practices. Another _good_ reference is https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe.

Answer (score 38):

[Linux tip: Bash parameters and parameter expansions](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-bash-parameters.html?ca=drs-)

```
${PARAMETER##WORD}  Results in removal of the longest matching pattern from the beginning rather than the shortest.
for example
[ian@pinguino ~]$ x="a1 b1 c2 d2"
[ian@pinguino ~]$ echo ${x#*1}
b1 c2 d2
[ian@pinguino ~]$ echo ${x##*1}
c2 d2
[ian@pinguino ~]$ echo ${x%1*}
a1 b
[ian@pinguino ~]$ echo ${x%%1*}
a
[ian@pinguino ~]$ echo ${x/1/3}
a3 b1 c2 d2
[ian@pinguino ~]$ echo ${x//1/3}
a3 b3 c2 d2
[ian@pinguino ~]$ echo ${x//?1/z3}
z3 z3 c2 d2
```

Comment: some explanation for beginners like me would have been better like how these patterns are working

Answer (score 5):

I think the existing answers (while certainly accurate) miss the practical thrust of the OP's question.

The OP asked about:

```
echo ${0##/*}
```

My guess is that what they really saw in the code was:

```
echo ${0##*/}
```

The latter essentially means "delete everything up to, and including, the last slash (if any)". So it's a concise way of getting the name of the script without the path, regardless of how the script was called. It's equivalent<sup>*</sup> to

```
basename "$0"
```

but is arguably handier (and more efficient) if you're using it as a variable rather than just printing it to the console. (OTOH basename is more portable, whereas the parameter expansion is a bashism.)

<sup>* More or less. There are edge cases (such as file names that start with a space) where they don't output exactly the same thing.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Did you mean `##/*`, or `##*/`?

### ##/*

`${0##/*}` is a bit unusual - it will strip off the prefix `/...` from the start of `$0`.

It's an all-or-nothing operation: If `$0` starts with a slash (e.g. `/home/bob/myscript.sh`), then it will strip everything and return an empty string.  Otherwise (e.g. `./myscript.sh`) it will strip nothing and return the the whole of `$0`.

(The double `##` indicates that it should strip the longest match; a single `#` would only strip the first character, if it's a slash.)

I'm not sure how useful it is.  Perhaps it could be used to help detect if a script is called from an absolute path or not.

### ##*/

`${0##*/}` is more common - it will will strip off the prefix `.../` from the
start of `$0`.

e.g. if `$0` is `/home/bob/myscript.sh`, it will return `myscript.sh`.

The `##` again indicates that it should strip the longest match, so it will strip all slashes (`.../.../`).

(As opposed to a `#`, which will strip the first slash only, e.g. `/home/bob/myscript.sh` -> `home/bob/myscript.sh`, `a/b/myscript.sh` -> `b/myscript.sh`)