# How to get a substring after the last underscore (_) in unix shell script

Tags: shell, unix, substring

I have a String like this

```
this_is_test_string1_22
this_is_also_test_string12_6
```

I wanted to split and extracts string around the last underscore. 
That is i wanted the outputs like this

```
this_is_test_string1 and 22
this_is_also_test_string12 and 6
```

Can anyone help me how to get this in unix shell scripting.

Thanks. Sree

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do

```
s='this_is_test_string1_22'
```

In BASH:

```
echo "${s##*_}"
22
```

OR using sed:

```
sed 's/^.*_\([^_]*\)$/\1/' <<< 'this_is_test_string1_22'
22
```

**EDIT** for sh:

```
echo "$s" | sed 's/^.*_\([^_]*\)$/\1/'
```

Comment: And to achieve the desired output: `new="${s%_*} and ${s##*_}"; echo "$new"`

Comment: I am using /bin/sh interpreter and I am getting error when using echo sed 's/^.*_\([^_]*\)$/\1/' <<< 'this_is_test_string1_22'. The error is  "syntax error: `<' unexpected"

Comment: An explanation of the first method would be nice, i.e. what does ##* mean? Here is one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059794/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-0-syntax-with-variable-braces-and-hash-chara

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="_"}{last=$NF;NF--;print $0" "last}' <<EOF
> this_is_test_string1_22
> this_is_also_test_string12_6
> EOF
this_is_test_string1 22
this_is_also_test_string12 6
```

Answer (score 0):

So puting ideas from anubhava and glenn... Full Shell script can be... as follwoing. you can choose to output to a file or display on the commandline...

```
#!/bin/ksh

#FILE=/paht/to/file.txt or you can pass argument FILE=$1

 FILE=$1
 counter=`wc -l $FILE |cut  -d " " -f1`

x=1

while [ $x -le $counter ]
    do
            REC=`sed -n ${x}p $FILE`

            echo " ${REC%_*} and ${REC##*_} " >> output.txt

    let x=$x+1
done
```