# How do you interpret ${VAR#*:*:*} in Bourne Shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am using Bourne Shell. Need to confirm if my understanding of following is correct?

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash

$ VAR="NJ:NY:PA" <-- declare an array with semicolon as separator?

$ echo ${VAR#*} <-- show entire array without separator?
NJ:NY:PA  

$ echo ${VAR#*:*} <-- show array after first separator?
NY:PA

$ echo ${VAR#*:*:*} <-- show string after two separator
PA
```

Comment: No, it's not. There are no arrays in your code.

Comment: ok. So VAR is treated as string and echo is simply printing substring, by treating colon (:) as separator

Comment: Read the fine manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Comment: also that's not bourne, it's bash

Comment: bash *or* POSIX sh, but certainly not Bourne.

Comment: This is *almost* a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059794/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-0-syntax-with-variable-braces-and-hash-chara -- I'm sure we have an exact one somewhere.

Comment: ...btw, re: reference docs, you may find http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe more accessible than the manual.

Comment: BTW, putting a `*` on the end of that expansion form doesn't actually make much sense. There's no reason whatsoever to use `${var#*:*:*}` instead of `${var#*:*:}` -- since the single-`#` form expands to the **shortest** match possible, and `*` is allowed to expand to 0 characters, the final `*` does nothing.

Comment: ("Bourne Again" is a cute play on words, but Bourne is a shell from the 70s, whereas bash takes much more inspiration from ksh as it existed in the 80s, and *almost* complies with the 1992 POSIX sh specification, other than some very specific places -- such as `echo` -- where it takes liberties. They're from a different era, and calling bash "Bourne" pushes the truth).

Answer (score 2):

`${var#pattern}` is a [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) that expands to the value of `$var` with the shortest possible match for `pattern` removed from the front of the string.

Thus, `${VAR#*:}` removes everything up and including to the first `:`; `${VAR#*:*:}` removes everything up to and including the second `:`.

The trailing `*`s on the end of the expansions given in the question don't have any use, and should be avoided: There's no reason whatsoever to use `${var#*:*:*}` instead of `${var#*:*:}` -- since these match the smallest amount of text possible, and `*` is allowed to expand to 0 characters, the final `*` matches and removes nothing.

---

If what you *really* want is an array, you might consider using a real array instead.

```
# read contents of string VAR into an array of states
IFS=: read -r -a states <<<"$VAR"
echo "${states[0]}"  # will echo NJ
echo "${states[1]}"  # will echo NY
echo "${#states[@]}" # count states; will emit 3
```

...which also gives you the ability to write:

```
printf ' - %s\n' "${states[@]}"  # put *all* state names into an argument list
```