# Why does ${##parameter} always return 0?

Tags: bash, shell, parameter-expansion

Suppose that `parameter=value` is an internal variable in bash.
When I try `${#parameter}` in bash it returns a `5`. But when I try, for instance, `${##parameter}` or `${###parameter}` it always give back `0` in return.
Why it does not say that it is a substitution error as in other cases?

Comment: It doesn't always return `0`, it returns the value of `$#`. In this case, the variable's value was evidently 0.

Answer (score 3):

**Short version**

You could express `${##parameter}` as:

```
x=$#
${x#parameter}
```

and `${###parameter}` as:

```
x=$#
${x##parameter}
```

You are performing a prefix removal on `$#` (number of arguments passed to a script / function).

---

**Longer version**

If `parameter` has any special meaning, it would be likely specific to your environment.

```
$ echo \""${parameter}"\"
""
```

or even:

```
$ set -u
$ echo \""${parameter}"\"
bash: parameter: unbound variable
```

Now with that out of the way, quick look into [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

> `${#parameter}`
>
> The length in characters of the expanded value of parameter is substituted.

So with variable `parameter` not being set:

```
$ echo ${#parameter}
0
```

or with `set -u`:

```
$ echo ${#parameter}
bash: parameter: unbound variable
```

Additional `#` changed meaning to *Remove matching prefix pattern.* using: `${parameter#word}` or `${parameter##word}` syntax on `${#}`, i.e. number of argument passed to a script/function. Good way to see and understand that behavior would be:

```
$ f() { echo -n "$# " ; echo ${##parameter}; }
$ f
0 0
$ f a b c
3 3
```

As you see in first call `${#}` was `0` and (and attempting to strip prefix `"parameter"` does nothing to it really) and the second call value of `${#}` is `3`.

Prefix removal, the different between `#` and `##` is, when matching patterns whether shorted or longest match is stripped.

Comment: And to further emphasize how the meaning of `#` depends on context, `${####param}` would be parsed as an attempt to strip the longest prefix (with `##`) matching `#param` from the value of `$#`.

Comment: Well, bottom line really is, since `$#` will be a decimal number representaiton, any removal of `someString` prefix is essentially a `nop`. ;)

Comment: Right; I'm just pointing out that `#` can serve as a parameter name, (part of) an expansion operator, and part of the argument to that operator all in the same expression (regardless of whether the operation does anything to the value).

Answer (score 0):

Because ## is a special operator that removes a prefix.  See for instance here: [What is the meaning of the ${0##...} syntax with variable, braces and hash character in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059794/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-0-syntax-with-variable-braces-and-hash-chara)

Comment: But, if it removes a prefix, this syntax ```echo ${##param}``` (supposing param is unbound) should print nothing but yet it prints 0.

Comment: It does not work on `param` it works on `$#` and tries to strip `"param"` hence it's not trying to expand (access) variable of name `param` or whatever follows the `#`/`##`.