# How to run all shell commands in background by default with the output redirected as well?

Tags: linux, shell

I am looking for a way when I don't have to type:

`emacs abc.txt >/tmp/emacs.log 2>&1 &`

Instead just `emacs` command works like above.

All commands should be treated this way by default.
Is there a way to convert bash to behave this way? Or is there a shell that does this by default?

Comment: Making all commands behave this way would be terrible. All output redirected to file. Then you want to view that file, I suppose using `cat` or `tail`? Nope, their output also goes to that same file. You see the problem? Maybe your plan is to open a different shell that doesn't have this redirection and view file contents from there?

Comment: Your 'may be...' assumption is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would create a file `wtfmode` containing:

```
realpath="$PATH"
PATH="/"
command_not_found_handle() (
    cmd=${1##*/}
    PATH=$realpath
    "$@" > "/tmp/$cmd.log" 2>&1 &
)
```

Then `source wtfmode` manually to enable it, since putting it in `.bashrc` would could things very awkward.

Here's an example:

```
$ source wtfmode
$ ls
$ whoami
$ vim wtfmode
$ asdfasdfasdfsasdfasdf
$ ^C
$ ^C
```

Comment: I'd give this answer another + if I could. Didn't know about `command_not_found_handle`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Hah, I didn't know that either, so I used an explicit subshell here

Comment: Oh! I missed the `(` vs `{`, so had a completely different-and-wrong theory about why this worked. :)

Comment: You were still right, I checked :P

Comment: @thatotherguy Could you pl explain the ${1##*/} and thanks for the answer. I tried to figure that out but the documentation was not very helpful and easy to find.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059794/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-0-syntax-with-variable-braces-and-hash-chara)