# How to split a URL and Port stored in a variable and separate them into two variables URL and Port in bash

Tags: bash, variables, sed, grep

I was not able to find a simple example of how to split an URL from port number after extracting them from an API call. So I wanted to put it here for anyone else looking for an answer.

```
APP_ENDPOINT=htttps://www.someURL.com:3333
```

I need to separate the URL from the PORT to make another call with them separated such as to ssh into the server.

This is the answer I came up with, does anyone have a more succinct answer?

Also this was for URL and port number but should work for IP:port # as well.

I used grep with regex to put the port # in one variable and sed to remove the the : and port # from the endpoint variable.

```
APP_ENDPIONT=https://www.someURLorIP:port#
APP_PORT=$(grep -Eo "[0-9]+$" <<< $APP_ENDPOINT)
APP_ENDPOINT=$(echo $APP_ENDPOINT | sed "s/:[0-9]*//")
```

This will give you two variables with the URL/IP and the port in their respective variables.

Comment: You could avoid external calls to `grep` and `sed` and just use *bash parameter expansion* https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/bash-shell-parameter-substitution-2.html

Comment: Conventionally, you would put the answer included in your question into an actual answer...

Answer (score 3):

I will do like this:

```
APP_PORT=${APP_ENDPIONT##*:}

APP_ENDPOINT=${APP_ENDPIONT%:*}
```

And you can lookup the meaning of `${APP_ENDPIONT##*:}` and `${APP_ENDPIONT%:*}` in [what-is-the-meaning-of-the-0-syntax-with-variable-braces-and-hash-chara](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059794/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-0-syntax-with-variable-braces-and-hash-chara)